# translating from corba to slice

Tags: corba, ice

I'm trying to translate corba `.idl` file into ZeroC ICE `.ice` file.
They are very similar, although I have problem with lines:

```
interface Item {
      readonly attribute string name;
      void action(inout long a);
      ...
}
```

Can `attibute` be defined in slice? What can be done to translate `inout` parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From: http://www.zeroc.com/iceVsCorba.html:

> Slice does away with many of the unnecessary complexities of CORBA
>   IDL, such as attributes, inout parameters, contexts, and the
>   complexities of Objects-by-Value (OBV).

You have to define accessor functions directly and split inout parameter into two.